# Expected value of difference of two ordered statistics

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expected-value, order-statistics

I have some questions about computing the difference between two order statistics.

Given that for $i,j \in \{1,\cdots,\lambda\}$, denote Bin(s,p) to be a binomial random variable with success probability $p$ and $s$ independent experiments. Define $W_j=Bin(s_1,p)-Bin(n-s_1,p)$ for some $p \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $Z_i=Bin(s_2,p)-Bin(n-s_2,p)$ for some $p \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

All $W_j,Z_i$ are i.i.d random variables with $s_1<s_2$. Can we show that for arbitrary $\lambda \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists some $\epsilon >0$

$E(\min_{i\in \{1,\cdots,\lambda \}}Z_i)-E(\min_{j\in \{1,\cdots,\lambda \}}W_j)\geq \epsilon >0$ for $s_2>s_1$?

Or is my claim false? How do we see it?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your claim is equivalent to showing that whenever $s_2>s_1$, $\mathbb E[\min_{i} Z_i]>\mathbb E[\min_i W_i]$.

Comment: Is the $\epsilon$ important here?  If so, can it depend on $n$ and $p$  as well as $\lambda$? @P.Quinton's reformulation would suggest it is not important

Comment: @P.Quinton Yes, you are right. But I just get stuck at this step.

Comment: @Henry $\epsilon$ does not matter. What I want to show is that the difference of expectations is positive. It can depend on n, p as well as $\lambda$.

Comment: Intuitively my thought would be that $Z_i$ has first order stochastic dominance over $X_j$ when $s_2>s_1$ so similarly with $Z_{(1)}$ and $X_{(1)}$ and thus $E[Z_{(1)}] >E[X_{(1)}]$

Comment: @Henry Thank you for your reply! Stochastic dominance may be a potential way to show it. However, there are two problems. One is that how to show $Z_{(1)}\geq_{st} W_{(1)}$. The second one is that if we had stochastic dominance, it seems that it only implies $E[Z_{(1)}] \geq E[W_{(1)}]$ rather than strict inequality $E[Z_{(1)}] > E[W_{(1)}]$ .

Comment: @Lin It may depend on definition but I think my definition of first order stochastic dominance would give the strict inequality of expectations (if they exist): $P(Z_{(1)} >c) \ge P(W_{(1)} >c)$ for all $c$ and $P(Z_{(1)} >c) \gt P(W_{(1)} >c)$ for some $c$

Comment: @ Henry Yes, you are right. If we use your definition, we may be able to obtain strict inequality. Then, it remains to show $Z_i \geq_{st} W_j$ and then $Z_{(1)} \geq_{st} W_{(1)}$. While I think it may be not easy to compute their CDF directly. Do you have any suggestions?